# Angular file upload - return name uploaded file

Tags: hash, callback, angular-file-upload

I'm using an angular-file-upload directive. When I uploading file I getting file's name before upload on callback.

```
$$hashKey: "object:19"_file: FilelastModified: 1429780959000lastModifiedDate: Thu Apr 23 2015 12:22:39 GMT+0300 (MSK)name: "av_1.png"size: 1278type: "image/png"webkitRelativePath: "" trueisUploading: falsemethod: "POST"progress: 100removeAfterUpload: false

name: "av_1.png" - name before upload
```

But I need to get name of file after upload. Name turns in 16 bit encoding and looks like `68b714b12c6a4336500a4c5a4b53c60e.png` for example.

How can I return file's name after upload?